# Office blurry on windows 10

Tags: microsoft-office

One user is experiencing blurry `Office 2013` on external monitor. OS - `Windows 10`

I might try `Disable display scaling on high DPI settings` in properties -> compatibility tab of exe, But the tab is missing. How can I make tab to appear?

Is there other options to correct blurry experience? Because desktop and other apps are good quality, except for office.

Answer (score -1):

Someone described how to add the office exe to the registry so the tab appears:

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/blurry-fonts-poor-display-scaling-office-2013

Comment: Link only answers are bad because the links die/go bad... Instead, copy the relevant part from the website and keep the link where you copied it from :)